# Chrome developer Tool - window dimensions disappeared

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

It may sound silly but all of a sudden I have no window dimensions box in the top right corner of the inspector and I cannot turn it on.

What I mean is:
[image: chrome]

(picture comes from another topic on stackoverflow)

Would appreciate your help!

Comment: I have the same question. That little floater was very handy and I'm lost without it frankly. I'm going to check and see if an extension is available to fill the gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We noticed the same here in our office, but it has nothing to do with your browser configuration. In fact, you can test this by resetting it in the setting panel.

There's nothing about this on Google's Chrome dev blog, so either they dropped the feature or it's bugged, but we can only wait for Google to fix it.

Comment: what a pity :( thank you very much. Have you found any alternative?

Comment: Enabling the ruler in settings helps a little, else the "Page Ruler" extension can help as well, but both don't offer the same as the box you were talking about.

Comment: well, thanks for the help anyway! Hope it will be brought back!

Answer (score 0):

Someone has opened a issue for this over at bugs.chromium.org (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=591718)

Head on over there and star it so it gets more attention and hopefully a quick fix.

@dandy I took the liberty of adding your screenshot to that issue.

Comment: It's not my screenshot but I hope no one will get offended ;)
I'll comment on that issue.